# How can I redirect all .eu pages to .nl using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I have two domains, a .eu domain and a .nl domain.

I've already added a rule that rewrites www to non www and http to https.

Now I need all pages to go to the .nl domain by default.

I've tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%.nl{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

But that is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your htaccess try with below, it is tested [here](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=c81661c0-7843-57f0-9d37-8bb2f6125792).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)\.(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: I've got no errors but it still doesn't redirect to the .nl domain. Even in incognito mode (cleared cache) it stays on .eu

Comment: actually in your last rule you are misplacing % of request uri `%1%.nl{REQUEST_URI}` if you can check.

Comment: Thanks this works kinda, but now my pages stopped working. For example this line `RewriteRule   ^vragen vragen.php [QSA,L]` if I go to website.nl/vragen I am shown a 404 page. All my pages except the homepage stopped working.

Comment: And if I go to website.eu without www. I am redirected to website.eu.nl